# Change Revolute Joint Axis in SimMechanics

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink, simscape, simmechanics

I am leveraging SimMechanics, SimElectronics, and Simulink to model a quadcopter system for an embedded system class project ( [files here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ElH85QJC5WeTRtSTg1b2VrdWM/view?usp=sharing) ). I have generated a 2nd Generation SimMechanics model of an F450 quadcopter frame, including the motors and propellers. We were hoping to develop a model of a quadcopter with only a single rotational degree of freedom around either the x or y axis. I was hoping to model this with a revolute joint connecting the quadcopter frame to the "world frame". However, the "revolute joint" block in SimMechanics only acts around the z-axis. How can I change the axis of rotation for a revolute joint?

It appears that another individual has asked the [same question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/136908-how-to-change-the-axis-of-action-of-a-revolute-joint-in-simmechanics-second-generation), but no one has yet responded to his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Assembling Multibody Models](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ug/assembling-multibody-systems.html) in the SimMechanics documentation, in particular the section on "orienting joints":

> To obtain the motion expected in a model, you must align its various
>   joint motion axes properly. This means aligning the joints themselves
>   as observed or anticipated in the real system. Misaligning the joint
>   axes may lead to unexpected motion but it often leads to something
>   more serious, such as a failure to assemble and simulate.
>
> You can specify and change joint alignment by rotating the connection
>   frames local to the adjoining body subsystems. For this purpose, you
>   specify rotation transforms using Rigid Transform blocks, either by
>   adding new blocks to the body subsystems or, if appropriate, by
>   changing the rotation transforms in existing blocks within the
>   subsystems.
>
> Why change the orientation of joints through body subsystem frames?
>   The primitives in a Joint block each have a predetermined motion axis,
>   such as x or z. The axis definition is fixed and cannot be changed.
>   Realigning the connection frames local to the adjoining body
>   subsystems provides a natural way to reorient joints while avoiding
>   confusion over which axis a particular joint uses.
>
> For an example of how to rotate joint connection frames, see [Model
>   Mount](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ug/model-pivot-mount.html).

So the answer is to use a [Rigid Transform](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ref/rigidtransform.html) block to change the orientation of the frames, you cannot change the axis of the revolute joint.

Comment: This response is really helpful! Thanks for providing the overview, and for providing the information so that I can read further. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change it in your CAD file. Change your propeller axis to align with z axis. But you should only change the propeller axis, not the whole body.